# difference with stackpointers in x86 and x86-64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel

I compared the output of the code compiled by `clang` with `-m32` and without, and couldn't help but notice that the 64-Bit part is missing the incrementing and decrementing of the stackpointer register in each method.

**32-Bit:**

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8                          # here
    mov eax, 0
    mov dword ptr [ebp - 4], 10
    mov dword ptr [ebp - 8], 5
    add esp, 8                          # and here
    pop ebp
    ret
```

**64-Bit:**

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov eax, 0
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 4], 10
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 8], 5
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Compiled with clang 3.5.1 and no optimizations turned on.

Why? What does the `x86-64` do different in terms of the stack compared to their 32bit counterpart?
I also noticed, that some compilers, namely `gcc` and `icc`, sometimes decrement the stackpointer, but never increment them after leaving the method? Or sometimes take more? `gcc` takes `16 bytes` steps from the stack. `icc` does some completely crazy stuff, though.

Comment: You should read the [ABI documentation](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf). What you are seeing is the usage of the so-called `red zone`. Rest assured, stack pointer is restored by the time the function exits in all cases.

Comment: You don't see an increment of the stack pointer because there either is a `mov rsp, rbp` or `leave` instruction. The stack must be aligned on 16 byte boundaries and this is done with an `and`, that is not invertible. There is no point in keeping track of how much the stack pointer has been decremented, it is just restored from the saved value. The alignment is also why data is allocated in chuck of 16 bytes.

Comment: You should also compare some other, non-`main` functions for some interesting differences.